# ElectronJs: Not able to install "install.js:22 throw err"

Tags: npm, electron, npm-install

I am starting with Electron js and I have stumbled on the very first step which is installed Electron.

I am running the following command to install electron provided at
[source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-prebuilt)

```
npm install electron-prebuilt --save-dev
```

Following is the result of the command

```
C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\electron apps\example>npm install electron-prebuilt --sa
ve-dev

electron-prebuilt@0.37.8 postinstall C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\electron apps\exa
mple\node_modules\electron-prebuilt
node install.js
C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\electron apps\example\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\ins
tall.js:22
throw err
^

Error: end of central directory record signature not found
at C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\electron apps\example\node_modules\yauzl\index.js
:167:14
at C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\electron apps\example\node_modules\yauzl\index.js
:473:5
at C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\electron apps\example\node_modules\fd-slicer\inde
x.js:32:7
at FSReqWrap.wrapper as oncomplete
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\vikas\Desktop
\electron apps\example\package.json'
npm WARN example No description
npm WARN example No repository field.
npm WARN example No README data
npm WARN example No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\vikas\AppData\
\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "electron-prebuilt"
"--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm v3.8.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! electron-prebuilt@0.37.8 postinstall: node install.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron-prebuilt@0.37.8 postinstall script 'node install
.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the electron-prebuilt pac
kage,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs electron-prebuilt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls electron-prebuilt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\electron apps\example\npm-debug.log
```

**Windows 8.1**

**NPM Version 3.8.9**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is bug and a workaround is provided on github : [Source](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt/issues/69#issuecomment-164636460)

Here is the workaround:

```
rm -rf ~/.electron/
rm -rf ~/.atom/
npm cache clear
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\electron apps\example\package.json` exist? If not try running `npm init` to create it, and then run `npm install electron-prebuilt --save-dev` again.

Comment: I have `package.json` in the example folder. `{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
`

Comment: @VikasBansal then I'd suggest moving your project to a path that doesn't contain any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. But opening the command prompt as administrator (Windows) and reinstalling electron fixed the issue.